# Не работает подсветка док-строк Python

Tags: дефект, подсветка-синтаксиса

В таком коде:

```python
def get_sum(a, b):
    """Возвращает a + b."""
    return a + b
```

док-строка подсвечивается как обычная строка, хотя логичней было бы подсвечивать её как комментарий, т. е. серым.

PS: Док-строкой считается текст в тройных кавычках (`"""`), находящийся в начале файла, класса, метода или функции.

Comment: [На SO используется внешняя подсветка синтаксиса](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/282647)

Comment: @Grundy только не Prettify, a Highlight.js уже давно )

Comment: @Nofate, но сути это не меняет :)

Comment: Ну, вообще, док-строка - это не комментарий, не понятно, зачем ее как комментарий подсвечивать.